# How to export pandas dataframe into json and retain original datetime format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb, datetime

I am working on a dataset and I applied **to_json()** method to export a pandas dataframe in a json file. I will then use this json file to upload to MongoDB. However I realise that the datetime format was converted to epoch timestamp. **How do I retain the datetime format** while exporting to JSON file as well as uploading the json file to MongoDB? Also, I do not want null fields in json output.

df:

```
    user_id     datetime
0   69490717    [{'checkin_date': 2021-02-01 00:00:00}]
1   67125777    [{'checkin_date': 2021-02-01 00:00:00}]
2   62747294    NaN
3   63216896    [{'checkin_date': 2021-02-01 00:00:00}]
4   51466797    [{'checkin_date': 2021-01-31 00:00:00}]
... ... ...
96  82758550    NaN
97  44662827    NaN
98  36376189    [{'checkin_date': 2021-01-18 00:00:00}]
99  71910948    [{'checkin_date': 2021-01-18 00:00:00}, {'checkout_date': 2021-01-20 00:00:00}]
100 54620533    NaN
```

Snippet of json output:

```
[{"user_id":62507249,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":1612051200000},{"checkout_date":1612051200000}]}, 
{"user_id":69546481,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":1612051200000}]}, ......]
```

Below is my code for converting to json:

```
jsonresult = df.T.apply(lambda row: row[~row.isnull()].to_json())
json_wrapped = "[%s]" % ",".join(jsonresult)

# write JSON to file
with open('jsonresult.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_wrapped)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `date_format='iso'` parameter in [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and for remove rows with missing values is possible use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
a = [{"user_id":1,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":pd.Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')},
                                     {"checkout_date":pd.Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')}]},
     {"user_id":2,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":pd.Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')}]},
     {"user_id":4,"datetime": np.nan}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df)
   user_id                                           datetime
0        1  [{'checkin_date': 2021-02-01 00:00:00}, {'chec...
1        2            [{'checkin_date': 2021-02-01 00:00:00}]
2        4                                                NaN
```

---

```
jsonresult = df.dropna(subset=['datetime']).to_json(date_format='iso', orient='records')
print (jsonresult)
[{"user_id":1,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":"2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
                          {"checkout_date":"2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]},
 {"user_id":2,"datetime":[{"checkin_date":"2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]}]
```

---

```
dictresult = df.dropna(subset=['datetime']).to_dict(orient='records')
print (dictresult)
[{'user_id': 1, 'datetime': [{'checkin_date': Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')},
                             {'checkout_date': Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')}]}, 
 {'user_id': 2, 'datetime': [{'checkin_date': Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00')}]}]
```

Comment: hi, the first part of your answer helps to certain extent, it essentially retains the date format but it converts the dates data type to strings so when I upload the json file to MongoDB, the dates are in string format instead of datetime. How do I retain the datetime format ?

Comment: my bad, I just realised that I did not specify in my question that I am uploading the json file to MongoDB. Will edit my question accordingly

Comment: @snow - Hmmm, if need json then all data are converted to strings, so no datetimes there.

Comment: @snow - Possible solution is convert values to dictonaries like change `.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='records')` to `.to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: i tried, it returns me a list of dictionaries and strings but I a unable to write to json. Error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

````
with open('jsonresult.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dictresult)
``

Comment: @snow - If need json, then it is impossible. Because json are strings only.

Comment: @snow - Maybe is necessary change method of write, e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860176/2901002)

Comment: @snow - But is seems `unix` or `iso` format is good way - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `datetime` column to `string` using [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(str)
```

Also, your code for converting this to `json` is unnecessary. You can do below:

```
jsonresult  = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: hi, my apologies i had to edit the question to present the actual problem better